# EhCache - not caching with spring data

Tags: java, spring, caching, jpa, ehcache

I have the following method:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 20000)
@Async
public void test() {

Operator operator = this.operatorRepository.findOne(1L);
System.out.println(operator.getName());

org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCache c = (EhCacheCache) cacheManager.getCache("example");
System.out.println("HIT: "+c.getNativeCache().getStatistics().getExtended().get().component(GetOutcome.HIT).count().value());
System.out.println("MISS_EXPIRED: "+c.getNativeCache().getStatistics().getExtended().get().component(GetOutcome.MISS_EXPIRED).count().value());
System.out.println("MISS_NOT_FOUND: "+c.getNativeCache().getStatistics().getExtended().get().component(GetOutcome.MISS_NOT_FOUND).count().value());

System.out.println(c.getNativeCache().getStatistics().cacheHitOperation().count().value());
System.out.println("MISS COUNT: " +c.getNativeCache().getStatistics().cacheMissCount());
System.out.println("HIT COUNT: " +c.getNativeCache().getStatistics().cacheHitCount());
System.out.println("MISS_EXPIRED COUNT: " +c.getNativeCache().getStatistics().cacheMissExpiredCount());
System.out.println("CACHE_SIZE: " + c.getNativeCache().getStatistics().getSize());

}
```

The output is:

```
HIT: 0
MISS_EXPIRED: 0
MISS_NOT_FOUND: 0
0
MISS COUNT: 0
HIT COUNT: 0
MISS_EXPIRED COUNT: 0
CACHE_SIZE: 0
```

As you can see i'm using jpa repositories (spring-data) for my db operations. i configured a 2nd level cache. and yet no hits\misses.   my Operator entity is annotated like this:

```
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
```

here is my xml configurations:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />

    <property name="url" value="${mysql_url}" />
    <property name="username" value="xxx" />
    <property name="password" value="xxx" />

    <property name="initialSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="100" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="15" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="10" />
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="10000" />
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="60000" />

    <property name="validationQuery" value="/* ping */ SELECT 1" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />

    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="300" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">

    <property name="packagesToScan"
        value="com.xxx.model, com.xxx.shared.model" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
            <property name="showSql" value="false" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" />
        </map>
    </property>

</bean>
```

and my cache xml:

```
<ehcache   name="test"> 
<cache name="example" maxElementsInMemory="1000" eternal="false"  statistics="true" 
    overflowToDisk="false" timeToIdleSeconds="0" timeToLiveSeconds="600">
    <cacheEventListenerFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"
        properties="replicateAsynchronously=false,replicatePuts=false
         ,replicateUpdates=true,replicateUpdatesViaCopy=false
         ,replicateRemovals=true"
        propertySeparator="," />
    <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory"
        properties="bootstrapAsynchronously=true, maximumChunkSizeBytes=5000000" />
</cache>

<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
    class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
    properties="peerDiscovery=automatic, multicastGroupAddress=230.0.0.1,
                multicastGroupPort=4446, timeToLive=32" />
<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
    class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
    properties="hostName=localhost, port=40001, socketTimeoutMillis=2000" />
</ehcache>
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

When using `@Cache` annotation, by default entities are cached in a region (cache) whose name equals to the fully qualified class name of the entity.

If you want the `Operator` entities to be cached in the `example` cache, you should add a `region` to `@Cache`, such as in the following example:

```
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE, region="example")
@Entity
class Operator {
    ...
}
```

Also - if cache works correctly - you should call `this.operatorRepository.findOne(1L);` twice of course to see any cache hits.